# How to remove space between heading and column in BS4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
.rowHeight{
    height: 100px;
}

.padding-0
{
    padding-right: 0px;
    paddig-left: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}


.cart{
    height:42px;
    width: 42px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>S-MART | WELCOME</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="syles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row rowHeight justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-10 padding-0">
                <h1 class="header">S-MART</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 padding-0">
                <img src="images/shopping_cart_PNG58.png" class="cart" alt="Shoppingcart" align="center"> </img>
            </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to remove the space between the Heading and the Image. Should look like "S-MART(IMAGE)". I am new to this so have been facing issues similar to these, some advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do (which is usually done to place div elements next to one another) is to give them the float: left property and set their widths so that they are close to one another. For example assign each of them an id (I chose myH1 and myH1_pic) then give the corresponding properties in the css file  (you may want to edit the widths):

```
<div class="row rowHeight justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-10 padding-0 " id="myH1">
       <h1 class="header">S-MART</h1>
    </div>
       <div class="col-md-2 padding-0 child" id="myH1_pic">
           <img src="images/shopping_cart_PNG58.png" class="cart" alt="Shoppingcart" align="center"> </img>
       </div>
  </div>
```

and for the css:

```
#myH1{
    width: 150px;
    float: left;}

#myH1_pic{
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
}
```

By the way you are missing a closing div tag.

Answer (score 0):

H1 tag contains default margin. You just need to remove it.
Hope this will help you.

```css
.rowHeight{
    height: 100px;
}

.padding-0
{
    padding-right: 0px;
    paddig-left: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
h1{
     margin : 0px;
}

.cart{
    height:42px;
    width: 42px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>S-MART | WELCOME</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="syles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row rowHeight justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-10 padding-0">
                <h1 class="header">S-MART</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 padding-0">
                <img src="images/shopping_cart_PNG58.png" class="cart" alt="Shoppingcart" align="center"> </img>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```